# How can I set environmental variables in bash using setenv?

Tags: bash, tcsh, setenv

I've a file containing all the environmental variables needed for an application to run in the following format...

```
setenv DISPLAY invest7@example.com
setenv HOST example.com
setenv HOSTNAME sk
...
```

How would I set the env. variables in bash using the above file? Is there a way to somehow use `setenv` command in bash?

Comment: It seems a silly question, but you got a very good answer, so well done.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a function named `setenv`:

```
function setenv() { export "$1=$2"; }
```

To set the envariables, source the file:

```
. your_file
```

Comment: The `eval` isn't necessary and avoiding it reduces some security risks: `setenv() { export "$1=$2"; }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improved version.

```
# Mimic csh/tsch setenv
function setenv()
{
    if [ $# = 2 ]; then
        export $1=$2;
    else
        echo "Usage: setenv [NAME] [VALUE]";
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete version for ksh/bash. It behaves like csh/tcsh setenv regardless of the number of arguments.

```
setenv () {
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        env
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ $1 == *[!A-Za-z0-9_]* ]]; then
        printf 'setenv: not a valid identifier -- %s\n' "$1" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    case $# in
        1)
            export "$1"
            ;;
        2)
            export "$1=$2"
            ;;
        *)
            printf 'Usage: setenv [VARIABLE [VALUE]]\n' >&2
            return 1
    esac
}
```